# commitlog flush to SSTable in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

how do we know that memtable has reached a threshold then it will flash to the SSTable disk, is there any command to find out? thank you

Answer (score 0):

memtable threshold is define in cassandra.yaml.
Also cassandra will automatically trigger flush when memtable threshold is reached or commit log is full.

most of the details can be found using command `nodetool tablestats`.

[nodetool tablestats](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTablestats.html)

[More on memtable flush](http://abiasforaction.net/apache-cassandra-memtable-flush/)